# How to recalculate bone roll in action keyframes or in pose mode

Tags: bones, pose-mode, actions

I hope my title is specific enough

Is there a way to recalculate the bone roll while I am editing an action? It seems like you can only do that in *Edit Mode* which goes back to the rest position automatically.

I need it to work while I'm not in rest position, but while in in the *Action Editor* moving between keyframes or in *Pose Mode* at least. I need it to clear rotation with respect to the global axis somehow.

I'm semi-new to Blender, so forgive me if I have the terminology wrong. Tell me if I need to explain more.

Here's the armature after I recalculated to bones so that they are straight:

[image: Nice bone roll]

Then I clicked back into an old action and it is like this:

[image: Messed up bone roll]

Consequently, I concluded that I need to recalculate the bone roll for all my key frames. Luckily, my actions are rather simple so I don't have many, but still, I can't see how to change bone roll in pose mode.

All those planes were re-rotated with 90 X rotation and 0 Z rotation to supposedly make it simpler to animate. We'll see about that! Anyway, when the roll gets messed up, all the planes get out of whack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the roll good for one pose, it will be messed up for a different pose, so I don't think it's a good approach: better set up the rig in edit mode so that every bone is parallel to the view plane (use "keep offset" instead of "connected"), then lock two rotation axis so that only the one needed is allowed. In this way you will never have planes deformations.

[image]

Comment: So, in other words, I have to re do my actions with the rotation for those axis locked?

Comment: I think so ....